# Open and Save files taking very long on 1904

Tags: 19.04

Another weird problem I have on 19.04: on my PC at home the file dialog seems to take forever.

No matter what program I use, opening a file or saving it takes minutes.

I dont have that problem on my notebook.

What could that be?

Comment: use command line to open a file and see if there are any messages. add the results to the question.

Comment: What do you mean with command line? When I use cat or nano it works pretty fast without any problems.